# Outer Reference error when grouping month and years

Tags: sql, sql-server

Getting the following error:

```
Each GROUP BY expression must contain at least one column that is not an outer reference
```

I'd like to have a listing of `calculatedDrugDistributionHistory` grouped by facilty, month, and year. I just want to take inventory of which facilities for which months have been imported into our system.

I have this query:

```
select 
    f.name,
    MONTH(cddh.dateGiven) as 'date_month',
    YEAR(cddh.dateGiven) as 'date_year' 
from 
    calculatedDrugDistributionHistory cddh
        inner join facilityIndividuals fi on fi.facilityIndividualId = cddh.facilityIndividualId
        inner join facilities f on fi.facilityId = f.facilityId
group by 
    f.name,
    'date_month',
    'date_year'
order by
    f.name,
    'date_month',
    'date_year'
```

Comment: the error you are getting is because 'date_month' &  'date_year' 
 will come in picture once this group by and orde by will execute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You **can't** use aliases in group by clause. Try this way:

```
select 
    f.name,
    MONTH(cddh.dateGiven) as date_month,
    YEAR(cddh.dateGiven) as date_year 
from calculatedDrugDistributionHistory cddh
inner join facilityIndividuals fi on fi.facilityIndividualId = cddh.facilityIndividualId
inner join facilities f on fi.facilityId = f.facilityId
group by 
    f.name,
    MONTH(cddh.dateGiven),
    YEAR(cddh.dateGiven) 
order by
    f.name,
    date_month,
    date_year
```

Comment: Thanks for the resposne Parado - your answer makes sense, but I am getting error that `dateGiven' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY`

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
name,
date_month,
date_year 

FROM

(select F.NAME,MONTH(cddh.dateGiven) as date_month,
    YEAR(cddh.dateGiven) as date_year

from 
    calculatedDrugDistributionHistory cddh
        inner join facilityIndividuals fi on fi.facilityIndividualId = cddh.facilityIndividualId
        inner join facilities f on fi.facilityId = f.facilityId)TEMP
group by 
    name,
    date_month,
    date_year
order by
    name,
    date_month,
    date_year
```

Please Use this an update

Regards

Ashutosh Arya

Answer (score 0):

Two problems.  First, you are using single quotes for column aliases.  Use double quotes or square brackets.  Second, you need to include all columns in the `select` clause without aggregation function should be in the `group by`:

```
select f.name, MONTH(cddh.dateGiven) as date_month, YEAR(cddh.dateGiven) as date_year'
from calculatedDrugDistributionHistory cddh
        inner join facilityIndividuals fi on fi.facilityIndividualId = cddh.facilityIndividualId
        inner join facilities f on fi.facilityId = f.facilityId
group by  f.name, MONTH(cddh.dateGiven), YEAR(cddh.dateGiven)
order by f.name, date_month, date_year;
```

You can use the column aliases in the `order by`, but not the `group by`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use aliases in `GROUP BY`, and if you could, you shouldn't write them with single quotation mark:

```
select 
    f.name,
    MONTH(cddh.dateGiven) as date_month,
    YEAR(cddh.dateGiven) as date_year 
from 
    calculatedDrugDistributionHistory cddh
        inner join facilityIndividuals fi on fi.facilityIndividualId = cddh.facilityIndividualId
        inner join facilities f on fi.facilityId = f.facilityId
group by 
    f.name,
    MONTH(cddh.dateGiven),
    YEAR(cddh.dateGiven)
order by
    f.name,
    date_month,
    date_year
```